# UWP - adding items to ListView dynamically cause crash

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-10, uwp

I have a listview defined like this:

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="phonesListView" 
    Grid.Row="5"
    Background="Black"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    Foreground="Gray"  >

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid 
                        Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ComboBox 
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Background="Black"
                            Foreground="White">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Home" IsSelected="True"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Type}"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Office"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Fax"/>
                    </ComboBox>

                    <Button
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Height="30"
                            Width="30"
                            Foreground="Black"
                            Margin="0, 5, 0, 5"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="RemovePhone">
                        <Button.Background>
                            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/appbar.close.png" />
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>

                </Grid>

                <TextBox 
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Background="White"
                    Foreground="Black"
                    FontSize="20"
                    InputScope="TelephoneNumber"
                    Text="{Binding Number}"/>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I have an  `private ObservableCollection<Phone> numbers = new ObservableCollection<Phone>();`

In constructor I call `phonesListView.ItemSource = numbers;`

And on some button click I want to add new item to the listView so I call a method:

```
private void AddPhone(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Phone phone = new Phone("", Types.HOME);
    numbers.Add(phone);
}
```

But after button click to add a item the app crashes and `App.g.i.cs` is called and `global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` is highlighted

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
```

[image: This is e parameter]

I'm really new to Universal Windows App, and I read that this is called when something is wrong with XAML code. Could you help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: no other info on the exception when you let it crash ? If you put `e` to **watch** no more info ? Also from what I see in your XAML there is not AddPhone button, only remove

Comment: I added parameter value. And AddPhone is handler for button outside listView

Comment: To be honest I don't see any issue in the provided code. So the error is someplace else, if you provide more code maybe me or someone else will be able to help you out

Comment: Please provide the error your are receiving?

Comment: Hover your mouse over the `e` on your unhandled exception and it will tell us more info

Comment: Can you post your Phone model code and the XAML where your AddPhone button is defined please

Comment: Upload your sample to OneDrive and give us a link.

Comment: Just embed  Phone phone = new Phone("", Types.HOME); numbers.Add(phone); in try catch and you'll see the exception details.

Comment: The error is coming deep inside the windows presentation layer where all the "magic" happens.  The best way to drill down is to single step into the application and note the last area/function/statement that was executed.  Then you can selectively remove the XAML statements until you find the one causing the issue.  From there you will be able to focus on just that area and determine which of the parameters may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use `ItemsSource="{x:Bind Mode=TwoWay}"`

The only way (but not the best, I think) where I could dynamically update a listview was making a method that handle a button event where I add a new element (calling the addmethod) and updating the ItemsSource property of the list view.

```
private  void AnadeDoctorAppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

              Doctor A = new Doctor("Mapache", "dentista", "La calle", "La vida", "Lo que sea", "Direccion", "olos");

    ViewModel.AnadeDoctor = A;
    ListaDePrueba.ItemsSource = ViewModel.ColeccionDoctores;

}
```

It Works, but I think that is not true Databinding.